# Stan_glm equivalent in Python

Tags: python, linear-regression, bayesian, pymc3, pystan

I am trying build Market Mix Modeling (MMM) using a bayesian regression.
My dependent variable is "Sales_Units", and
My predictors are x1, x2, x3, x4
I also have prior information for the 4 predictors.

The bayesian regression model built in R as follows:

my_model_2022 <- stan_glm(Sales_Units ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5,
prior= normal (c (0.4, 0.1, 1.0, 1.2), c (0.01, 0.01, 0.2, 0.3) ), data=Mydata)

My question is: How do I replicate the above model in Python, and which package should I use; PyMC3 or PyStan, Bambi? And how do I specify the priors within the model?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use bambi to use this formula syntax in python: https://bambinos.github.io/bambi/main/index.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you @OriolAbril for the answer. How do I specify the priors for more than one variables in BAMBI?

Comment: I think using multiple keys in the dictionary similar to https://bambinos.github.io/bambi/main/notebooks/getting_started.html#Specifying-priors